# How do I move in a tree to the next child?

Tags: perl, hash, tree, move

I try to build a tree on my own. I start with an anonymous hash and created the first knot ("there"). From there on I want to create a child knot, but what I attempted didn't work.

```
use Data::Dumper;
$tree = {};
$tree->{'these'} = {};
$tree = $tree->{'these'};
$tree->{'are'} = {};
print Dumper $tree;
```

`$tree = $tree->{'these'};` doesn't move `$tree` to the anonymous hash.
The output is

```
$VAR1 = {
          'are' => {}
        };
```

but I wanted it to be

```
$VAR1 = {
          'these' => {
                     'are' => {}
                     }
        };
```

Any idea is very appreciated.

Comment: See tutorial [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) (reference is [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)) and "cookbook" of sorts, [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a look at the last two lines you wrote:

```
$tree->{'are'} = {};
print Dumper $tree;
```

After that, how can `$tree` possibly be a reference to a hash that contains only the key `these` as you say you want?

The problem is that you're trying to use `$tree` for two different things:

- A reference to the root node.
- A reference to the node to which you want to add elements.

Those two hashes/nodes aren't always the same, so we need two variables. In fact, I'll use three for completely clarity.

- `$tree`, a reference to the root node.
- `$node` the node we are creating.
- `$parent` the node into which we want to insert.

We start by creating a root node and assign it to `$tree`

```
my $tree = {};
```

We don't want to lose track of the root node, so we'll never assign to `$tree` again. We can assign to elements of the hash referenced by `$tree`, though.

The next time we insert, we want to insert into the root node.

```
my $parent = $tree;
```

Now it's time to start adding new nodes.

```
my $node = {};
$parent->{these} = $node;
```

The next time we insert, we want to insert into the newly created node.

```
$parent = $parent->{these};
```

We insert again.

```
my $node = {};
$parent->{are} = $node;
```

And that's it! All together:

```
use strict;     # ALWAYS use this.
use warnings;   # ALWAYS use this.

use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my $tree = {};
my $parent = $tree;

{
   my $node = {};
   $parent->{these} = $node;
   $parent = $parent->{these};
}

{
   my $node = {};
   $parent->{are} = $node;
   $parent = $parent->{are};
}

print(Dumper($tree));
```

If that's clear, we can simplify a bit.

```
use strict;     # ALWAYS use this.
use warnings;   # ALWAYS use this.

use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my $tree = {};
my $parent = $tree;

$parent->{these} = {};
$parent = $parent->{these};

$parent->{are} = {};
$parent = $parent->{are};

print(Dumper($tree));
```

We can even take it a step further!

```
use strict;     # ALWAYS use this.
use warnings;   # ALWAYS use this.

use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my $tree = {};
my $parent = $tree;

$parent = $parent->{these} = {};   # Assignments are performed right-to-left.
$parent = $parent->{are} = {};

print(Dumper($tree));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I should at least use two variables. One for the tree itself and one for moving around. After reading your explanation everything seems very clear - wasn't so before.

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help. I was worried that I might have been too meandering :)

Comment: When I ask for help, a certain level of desperation is reached already. So easy step by step explaination is what I need. Thanx again.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $tree = {};
$tree->{these}->{are} = {};
print Dumper $tree;
```

Rationale: your original code keeps reassigning new values to `$tree`, overwriting the previously assigned value:

```
$tree->{'these'} = {};       # original assignment
$tree = $tree->{'these'};    # new assignment: now $tree is an empty hash ref
$tree->{'are'} = {};         # new assignment: now $tree contains { are => {} }
```

Here is another way to express your intent using another variable:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $tree = {};
my $child_tree = {};
$child_tree->{are} = {};
$tree->{these} = $child_tree;
print Dumper $tree;
```

Unrelated side note: **always** `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Thank you GMB! `$tree->{these}->{are} = {};` is doing, what it should, but for my case it is too static. So I go with your second solution, to grow a tree dynamically.